# screen capture and scrolling in a DOM element with casper.js

Tags: javascript, phantomjs, screenshot, screen-scraping, casperjs

Using casper.js to generate a screenshot of a specific DOM element's quite easy:

```
var casper = require('casper').create();

casper.options.viewportSize = { width: 1400, height: 900 };

casper.start('http://www.example.com', function() {
    this.captureSelector('myImage.png', '.myClass');
});

casper.run();
```

With this example i end up with 20 somewhat pixels on the left side which doesn't belong to the element...is there a way to scroll left before the screenshot's taken? And Furthermore: is there a way to set a specific width or height in myImage.png before the screenshot's taken?

Comment: You can check how CasperJS does the capture ([link](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/casper.js#L383)) and how the element bounds are determined ([link](https://github.com/n1k0/casperjs/blob/1.1-beta3/modules/clientutils.js#L403-L424)). You can try to refine that, but I don't think that scrolling with [`casper.scrollTo(20, 0)`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#scrollto) can help you here.